# Fazendo um botão ler as funções

Tags: javascript, funções, button

sou iniciante em programação e eu preciso de ajuda com a função de um botão, eu não sei como fazer esse botão "ler" os valores  de idade, a ideia do site é inserir as informações para ver se a pessoa requer ou não aposentadoria

isso é uma função de testes então tem bastante coisa faltando neste codigo como  a var nome

```
         function verificaAposentadoria()
            {



            var idade = document.getElementById("idade").value;
            var trabalho = document.getElementById("trabalho").value;
            var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

                idade = parseInt(idade)
                trabalho = parseFloat(trabalho)
                resultado = parseInt(resultado)
            var saida = "Olá, "+nome+", seu tempo é "+trabalho;

            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = saida;




            if ("trabalho">=60)  
            alert ("Você pode se aposentar")
            }






            </script>
```

Comment: Ainda tem erro no código: `if ("trabalho">=60)`... deveria ser `if (trabalho>=60)`... `trabalho` é uma variável e não uma string. É só remover as aspas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Html você pode fazer

```
<button type='button' onclick="verificaAposentadoria()"> Verificar </button>
```

Comment: muito obrigado amigo :^) ajudou bastante

Comment: Foi nada @Calado ! Boa sorte nos seus estudos :D